# Flutter - Resulting set from filtering list gives null values (is a bug?)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sdk

I have this code

```
Set<String> set = list.where(someFilter)
                      .map(someMapping)
                      .where((item) => item != null)
                      .toSet();
```

And the resulting set is something like

```
   {
    item1, 
    item2,
    item3,
    null,
    null,
    null
   }
```

Did I wrote something wrong or is that a bug?

Comment: item1, item2, item3 are String variables ?

Comment: What are you doing in your map? I don't think the output is possible. A set won't contain same value twice

Comment: yes, in this example item1, item2, item3 are strings variable returned from the map function. 
In practice I have a list of objects (all the same class), filtering by some conditions and then map to a particular string.

Comment: Is there some update?

Comment: Having this exact issue. A list with 30 non-null values turns into a set with 30 non-null values, and 2 null values. Using dart 2.12